# Parameterize shared example with rspec2

Tags: rspec2

How I can parameterize to pass information between shared_example/include_examples?

In my specific case, I want to feed several constants to shared_example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer by myself... (I was hunting for answer for this two hours.. found this just after posting this)

At David Chelimsky's site, in article "[Specifying mixins with shared example groups in RSpec-2](http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2010/11/07/specifying-mixins-with-shared-example-groups-in-rspec-2/)," I found that shared_example can accept block parameters, and include_example can give parameters..

```
shared_example "example_1" do |param|
  it "does something" do
    xx.should == param
  end   
end
```

and later...

```
include_examples "example_1", :value_1
```

This work well with my case.

Note that, this parametalization is documented as cucumber feature, so I could find [RSPec::Core document at Relish](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs), but not in the class documentation.